Issue with Feign clients in Spring Modulith integration tests using @ApplicationModuleTest
I'm working on a Spring Boot 3.1 project using Spring Modulith 1.2.4, with two distinct modules: amadeus and collinson. Each module has its own Feign client:

amadeus.client.AmadeusFeignClient
collinson.client.CollinsonFeignClient

The application runs perfectly in production, but I am encountering issues when running integration tests for each module using @ApplicationModuleTest. For example:

When running the integration test for AmadeusService, I get an error saying that CollinsonFeignClient is not available:
No bean named 'com.demo.app.collinson.client.CollinsonFeignClient' available 
When running the test for CollinsonService, I get a similar error for the AmadeusFeignClient: No bean named 'com.demo.app.amadeus.client.AmadeusFeignClient' available 

Here are the annotations I'm using for my tests:
@ApplicationModuleTest
class AmadeusServiceIT {
    // test implementation
}

@ApplicationModuleTest
class CollinsonServiceIT {
    // test implementation
}


However, if I switch from @ApplicationModuleTest to @SpringBootTest, the tests run without issues, which suggests that Feign clients might be ignoring the module isolation provided by @ApplicationModuleTest.
My understanding is that @ApplicationModuleTest should isolate the beans per module during testing, but it appears that Spring Cloud OpenFeign is not respecting this isolation, causing cross-module beans to be required.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue with Feign clients in a Spring Modulith context?
Is there a way to configure @ApplicationModuleTest or Feign to respect the module isolation during tests?

After some investigation, I found the root cause of the problem. It was placing @EnableFeignClients on the main com.demo.app.DemoApplication class
package com.demo.app
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Which led to all Feign clients being loaded regardless of the module I was testing. This caused integration tests from different modules to fail because they tried to load Feign clients from unrelated modules.
Solution:

Remove @EnableFeignClients from the root application class
Create a configuration class in each module with @EnableFeignClients. I moved the @EnableFeignClients annotation to a configuration class inside each module. This ensures that only the Feign clients related to that specific module are loaded.

package com.demo.app.collinson
@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients
public class CollinsonModuleConfig {
}

package com.demo.app.amadeus
@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients
public class AmadeusModuleConfig {
}

Result:
By scoping @EnableFeignClients to each module, I achieved proper isolation between modules, ensuring that the correct Feign clients are loaded during testing. This approach resolved the errors related to missing Feign client beans from unrelated modules.
